# Is it possible to decompile a stylesheet that was compiled by Saxon?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

We have a set of compiled XSL style sheets (.sxx extension) that were provided to us for publishing purposes by a customer. The provider received these during a transfer of data during a company merger, and may not have the original .xsl source style sheets, nor is anyone who created them involved on the project any longer.

**Is there a way to de-compile what we have in order to make edits?**

We were provided a Saxon 9.0.0.3 JAR file as to run these. I believe it to be the PE edition.

Answer (score 2):

This mechanism for compiling stylesheets was dropped a long time ago, it shouldn't be confused with the current .SEF files.

sxx files, if my memory serves me, were produced by using Java serialization of the "Templates" object, which is basically a dump of the internal expression tree. They will only work with the Saxon release that was used to compile them.

In principle you could load the files with 9.0.0.3 and inspect the expression tree with a debugger, and with a lot of effort you could write some utility that inspects the tree and produces human-readable output. But it would be a very laborious process.